# How to translate "web-project" into Chinese?

Tags: translation

"web-project" is an idea of complete service on the web, e.g.: some news site, personal website, facebook, twitter...

For 'web' is most likely '网络' should be used.

The problem is 'project'
'计划' does not suit, cause it sounds more like 'organization of network, network configuration.

'工程' makes the phrase as a name of specialization 'Network Engineering'.

Any right ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Taiwan, we use 專案. As for the web part, we simply say Web, or 網站, if you insist a Chinese name. So a web project would be a Web 專案 or a 網站專案. Same goes for other projects, such as an iOS 專案 for an iPhone app, an Android 專案 for an Android app.

If you're working on a project, you could say that 你在做專案.

Wikipedia page for [Project management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management) corresponds to [專案管理](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86). As an aside, a project manager is called a 專案經理 or a 專案管理員.

Note that, as @SodaPop suggested, in China they call it [項目](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86).

Comment: Yes, '网站项目' is the term I need! Beg you, please, remove Italic font style from Chinese characters otherwise they are mostly unreadable

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use 项目. And for web I don't know I think 网络 sounds more like networks/internet.

Answer (score 0):

"Web project", is typically a technical or engineering phrase which can be translated as "网站" OR "网站工程" OR "网站项目" in Chinese.
All of them are OK.

"网络" is not appropriate here, which stands for "Networking" in most cases.